# How to get the numbers of inputs puppeteer java

Tags: javascript, java, puppeteer

here is a code that varies every day (some days have more inputs than others) :

```
<input id="bot1" value="005">
<input id="bot2" value="054">
<input id="bot3" value="854">
<input id="bot4" value="213">
<input id="bot5" value="478">
<input id="bot6" value="355">
```

I need something to count the numbers of inputs

my test:

```
for(i=0; i<50; i++){
try{
  await pageroteiro.waitForSelector('input#bot'+i)
}catch(e){
  number = i;
console.log(number);
}
```

I tried too:

```
   for(i=0; i<50; i++){
while(await pageroteiro.waitForSelector('input#bot'+i) == ''){
  var number = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR. Use:**

```
const count = await pageroteiro.$$eval("input", els =>
   els.filter(input => input.id.startsWith("bot"))
      .length)
```

**Long answers:**
You are confusing two things different:

**1-** You need a waitForSelector function to make sure that the page is fully-loaded. You can't use a "variable element" for this. Choose an html tag that follows the inputs, or their parent. For example, if the full code is:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
     <input id="bot1" value="005">
     <input id="bot2" value="054">
</div>
<div id="anotherDiv"> ... </div>
```

You can now use:

```
pageroteiro.waitForSelector("#parentDiv") // or #anotherDiv
```

**2-** Now, you can count the div with a function:

```
const count = await pageroteiro.$$eval("input", els =>
   els.filter(input => input.id.startsWith("bot"))
      .length)
```